# Why doesn't input minlength check work with initial value?

Tags: html

Consider the following form:

```html
<form>
  <input type="text" minlength="5" value="1234">
  <button type="submit">submit</button>
</form>
```

When I click the submit button without changing anything, the minimum length validation doesn't work and the form submits successfully.

But after changing the input value, e.g. `1234 -> 12345 -> 1234`, the validation works and the form does not get submitted.

Why?

Answer (score 15):

This is by design. The `minlength` attribute only validates a field once it has been edited by the user. It doesn't validate the field if its value hasn't been changed, *even if that value doesn't meet the constraint*. From the [spec](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/form-control-infrastructure.html#setting-minimum-input-length-requirements:-the-minlength-attribute) (emphasis mine):

> **Constraint validation**: If an element has a minimum allowed value length, **its dirty value flag is true**, its value was last changed by a user edit (as opposed to a change made by a script), its value is not the empty string, and the JavaScript string length of the element's API value is less than the element's minimum allowed value length, then the element is suffering from being too short.

If you need to validate the value regardless of whether the user has since edited the field, see Racil Hilan's answer (although their statement about the `minlength` attribute not being supported everywhere doesn't imply anything and is largely irrelevant — as shown, this is clearly by design; if anything it shows that the browsers that *do* support the attribute support it *fully*).

Comment: It's ironic how you called my answer irrelevant and you actually did the same. Irrelevant is relative here. You see, if the goal of SO is to only explain, then you are right that the first half of my answer is irrelevant. And if the goal of SO is to provide a working solution, then my answer is relevant and yours is irrelevant :P. Truth is, the goal of SO is both, explain and provide a solution. That exactly what both of us did. You explained, then referenced my answer as a solution, while I provided a solution first then explanation referencing your answer. It's ok, no offence taken :)

Comment: @Racil Hilan: Well it was mostly just that 1 statement, I thought the rest of your answer was fine. Like I said, minlength works correctly in the places where it *is* supported anyway, so the number of places that support it doesn't matter. But I agree, the goal of SO is to do both. I think it's just a matter of which explanations we consider to be relevant. And maybe we have different perspectives on that. But fair enough!

Answer (score 8):

The `minlength` attribute is not supported in all browsers. You can use the `pattern` attribute instead. The `required` attribute is also needed, otherwise an input field with an empty value will be excluded from the validation.

Try this:

```html
<form>
  <input type="text" pattern=".{5,}" required value="1234">
  <button type="submit">submit</button>
</form>
```

The added benefit of using the `pattern` attribute is that it validates initial values, so you will not have the issue that you've seen with the `minlength` attribute which doesn't validate initial values (as explained in details by BoltClock's answer). The downside, though, is that the validation message is not as elegant. For example, the message in Chrome is "Please match the requested format" for `pattern` and "Please lengthen this text to 5 characters or more" for `minlength`.

Comment: Do you mean that I should not use minlength attribute for now?

Comment: It depends on what browsers you want to support. If you want to support as many browsers as possible, then you should not use the `minlength` attribute. See the what [browsers support it here](http://caniuse.com/#search=minlength).

Comment: Actually, now that I think about it... I wonder why pattern validation does take default values into account while minlength doesn't. On the surface it seems like an inconsistency, but I'm sure there must be a reason behind that design decision.

Comment: `minlength` still is not supported in 2020?!?!?! even in major browsers like Chrome?! i am baffled by this

Comment: @oldboy What makes you think that it is not supported in Chrome? Chrome supported it a long time ago, even before the question was asked. And all major browsers now support it (except IE).

Comment: @RacilHilan locally testing it in my browser. if i set a `minlength='2'` and `required` on an `input[type=text]`, it still submits the `form` even when the value of the `input` element is only 1 character long. please test it for yourself and let me know what happens

Comment: @RacilHilan have you been able to test it?

Comment: @oldboy I don't know the issue you're facing. Create a new question and provide the code you're using so we can help you. The code snippet in this question works fine in Chrome exactly as described by the OP. Read the question and answers carefully, it only works if you type in some value in the text field. It doesn't work if you assign the value to the field in code. This is by design and it won't change unless the standards change.

Comment: @RacilHilan im talking about `minlength` and `maxlength`. regex works just fine. i was just surprised that standardized attributes like `minlength` and `maxlength` arent widely supported in 2020

Comment: @oldboy Yes, I knew you were talking about `minlength`. It was supported in Chrome a long time ago, even before the question above was asked. And it is widely supported by all major browsers now. As for `maxlength`, it was supported even much earlier than `minlength` and virtually since the beginning of HTML wide use.

Comment: well it doesnt validate or force the input to be validated on Chrome anymore. try testing what i told you to do above

Comment: Yes, it does, on Chrome and all other major browsers. That's what I've been telling you. If it's not working for you in Chrome as described by the question and answers above, then you have something else going on in your environment.

Answer (score 3):

You can use **placeholder="1234"** instead of **value="1234**"  and don't forget to put "**required**" into your input field. So it works after

```html
<form role="form">
  <input type="text" name="number" minlength="5" placeholder="1234" required>
  <button type="submit">submit</button>
</form>
```